# Setting sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated hides translated content elements on root page (inversed behaviour)

Tags: content-management-system, overlay, typo3, multilingual, typoscript

I've setup a multilanguage (german [default], english, japanese) TYPO3 project with Templavoila and want to hide non translated content elements. Therefore I defined `sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated`. Generally this does work well but has an unexpected side effect on the root/homepage. If the overlay mode it set to `hideNonTranslated` no content will show up on the homepage at all while non translated content is hidden on all subpages as expected.
Below is my typoscript showing the language setup.

```
config{
    sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
    sys_language_mode = strict
    linkVars = L
    uniqueLinkVars = 1
    tx_cooluri_enable = 1
    redirectOldLinksToNew = 1
}

// ger
[globalVar = GP:L = 0]
    config{
        sys_language_uid = 0
        language = de
        locale_all = de_DE.UTF-8
        htmlTag_langKey = de-DE.utf8
    }
[global]

// en
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
    config{
        sys_language_uid = 1
        language = en
        locale_all = en_US.UTF-8
        htmlTag_langKey = en-US.utf8
    }
[global]

// jp
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
    config{
        sys_language_uid = 2
        language = jp
        locale_all = jp_JP.utf8
        htmlTag_langKey = jp-JP.utf8      
    }
[global]
```

How could I track down what causes that issue. What do I have to change in order to get the expected behaviour?
I really can't tell what's wrong with my setup. So any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the "issue".
It was caused by a small difference in the page layout on the homepage in comparison to subpages. The homepage uses additional flexible content elements provided by Templavoila. These have to be configured to appear in all languages by setting the language field inside the fce to `[All]` instead of `Default`.